# windows 8.1 app offline login

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-8.1, offline

I am creating a windows 8.1 app. I need to find a solution so a user can login when the internet connection is offline. I had the idea to use the local windows account to login. I was not able to find an answer that works on windows 8.1. Anyone an idea how to create an offline login?

Comment: This is not a simple subject, I am trying to work on that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Retrieve and Save credentials Offline using the PasswordVault class

here is a sqmple of code :

1) Retrieving :

```
 // Find the PasswordCredential for a user with a specified resource
        private PasswordCredential FindCredentialsForResourceAndUsername(string resource,
        string username)
        {
            try
            {
                PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
                IReadOnlyList<PasswordCredential> credentials =
                vault.FindAllByResource(resource);
                foreach (var credential in (IEnumerable<PasswordCredential>)credentials)
                {
                    if (credential.UserName.Equals(username))
                    {
                        return credential;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }
            return null;
}
```

2)- Save Credentials :

```
 // Provide a resource which will be used to access the credentials later
    private void SaveUserCredentials(string username, string password, string resource)
    {
        try
        {
            PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
            PasswordCredential cred = new PasswordCredential(resource,
            username, password);
            vault.Add(cred);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
```

Comment: can resource point to the local windows user his/her credentials to login on windows?

Comment: resource is kind of Key (an aplication name for exemple). Any way, you must save credentials before retreive them. You cannot get the Windows credentials.